# make a condition in select an output based on two queues in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

[Queues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Puwwb.jpg)

I am trying to make a decision based on the size of the two queues. First decision (check condition) leads to the second decision which is depend on the queue size in the two queues. I can't code it right, i tried as shown but no accurate results from trying that condition .I want to take the decision based on: if the queue size in queue greater than 15000 and the queue size in queue1 equals 0 the agents will go to queue1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invert your condition:

> if the queue size in queue greater than 15000 and the queue size in queue1 equals 0 the agents will go to queue1

```
(queue.size() > 15000 && queue1.size() == 0) == false
```

So you simply write the condition for when they should enter `queue1` (`queue.size() > 15000 && queue1.size() == 0`) and then invert it, as this is when they should *not* enter `queue1`

Boolean logic can be a bit nasty. Another approach would be to switch around `queue` and `queue1´ to have a simpler-to-understand if-statement :)